# Question about a proof of Second Derivatve Test

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Partial Statement: Let $f$ be defined in a neighborhood of $c$ with $f'(c) = 0$. Then $f''(c) > 0 \implies f(c)$ is a local minimum of $f$

> Proof: Suppose  $f$ is defined in a neighborhood of $c$ with $f'(c) = 0, \ f''(c) > 0 $. $\color{red}{\text{It can be shown}}$ there's punctured neighborhood of $N = (c - r, c) \cup (c, c + s)$ of $c$ s.t. $\displaystyle{\frac{f'(x) - f'(c)}{x - c} > 0}$ for $x \in N$ meaning $f'(x) < 0$ for $x \in (c - r, c)$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \in (c, c + s)$. It follows $c$ is a local minimum as $f$ dips towards $c$ from the left and grows back up on the right of $c$.

My question is about the $\color{red}{\text{part in red of the quote above}}$. How does that follow? Here below is my attempt. If incorrect, what would be a better way to show that? Thanks.

By definition, $f$ is differentiable at $c$ if $\displaystyle{\forall\varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta>0 \ \left|\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} - f'(c)\right| < \varepsilon}$ for any $x$ with $0<|x - c| < \delta.$ Then $\displaystyle{\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} = f'(c)} > 0$. Applying the definition above one more time we get $\displaystyle{\frac{f'(x) - f'(c)}{x - c} = f''(c)} > 0$.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of sign of derivative at a point?

Comment: I could probably intuit that as my book doesn't use that terminology. A useful theorem I have is that $f'(x)\ge 0$ on the interior of some interval $I$ means $f$ is increasing on $I$.

Comment: If the derivative $f'$ is positive at point $c$ then the difference quotient $(f(x) - f(c)) /(x-c) $ is positive  for all $x$ in some deleted neighborhood of $c$. Why? This goes back to the sign of a function and sign of its limit. If the limit is positive then values of function being near to the limit must also be positive. $\epsilon, \delta$ stuff is used to express this in a more precise manner, but the idea is simple.

Comment: Apply this to $f''$ and then the difference quotient $(f' (x) - f'(x)) /(x-c) $ is positive in some deleted neighborhood of $c$. That's what the proof in question is saying.

Comment: You should have a look at the answer by Ben for a formal proof based on $\epsilon, \delta$ and try to grasp the meaning behind all that symbolic manipulation.

Comment: Good explanation Paramanand Singh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prerequisite is missing: $ f$ should be a $C^2-$ function.

From $f''(c)>0$ and the continuity of $f''$ we get a punctured neighborhood $N = (c - r, c) \cup (c, c + s)$ such that $f''(t) >0$ for all $t \in N.$

If $x \in N$, then there is, by the mean value theorem $t \in $ such that

$$\frac{f'(x) - f'(c)}{x - c}=f''(t).$$

Hence

$$\frac{f'(x) - f'(c)}{x - c} >0.$$

Comment: Do we really need continuity for $f''$? I think $f''(c) > 0$ is enough to say for $x$ sufficiently close to $c$ we have $f'(x) < f'(c)$ to the left and $f'(x) > f'(c)$ to the right. That would make $c$ a local min, right?

Comment: @Ben : your concern is right. Existence of $f''(c) $ is all we need.

Answer (score 4):

Per the part in red:

We have $f''(c) > 0$, or

$$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f'(x) - f'(c)}{x-c} = f''(c) > 0$$

Let's use $\frac{f''(c)}{2}$ as our $\varepsilon$. There is some $\delta$ such that for all $x$ if

$$0 < |x - c| < \delta \implies \left|\frac{f'(x) - f'(c)}{x-c} - f''(c)\right| < \frac{f''(c)}{2}$$
or
$$-\frac{f''(c)}{2} < \frac{f'(x) - f'(c)}{x-c} - f''(c)< \frac{f''(c)}{2} $$
$$\frac{f'(x) - f'(c)}{x-c} > \frac{f''(c)}{2} > 0$$

In order for the LHS to be $> 0$, for $x>c$ we must have $f'(x) > f'(c) = 0$.

Similarly, for $x < c$ we have $f'(x) < 0$.

Thus, $f$ is decreasing on some interval to the left of $c$ and increasing to the right, and so, $c$ is a local minimum.